# Custom UIToolbar resize with animation

Tags: xcode, uiview, uitoolbar

i'm using this piece of code to resize my custom UIToolbar to change width property

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.3 options:0 animations:^{
    self.navToolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
} completion:nil];
```

the code above, change width correctly but without animation,
could anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: try with minimum 1 sec duration. If this helps then there is something you have to do with animation duration to adjust you animation effect

Comment: i've changed duration but nothing changes.

Comment: What iOS? is it above 4?

Comment: I have tested your code with both a `UINavigationBar` & a `UIToolbar` and works fine. I guess it's something with your outlet... Do you instantiate the toolbar in Interface Builder or in code?

Comment: I don't know why but now it works, the Toolbar width now is changing with animation but not the UIBarButtonItems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` (iOS > 4.0) should fix the problem when the size change is not being animated.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
        delay:0.3 
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews 
        animations:^{
        self.navToolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
        }
       completion:nil
];
```