# iOS/Swift: Dynamically Resize a Toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app with a toolbar that can be resized. Basically, the toolbar can alternate between being at the bottom of the view and being at the top. When a button is pressed, it switches from one to the other. The problem is that when it is at the top, I want the size of the toolbar to expand to accommodate the status bar, but I don't know how to do this.

I've seen some solutions for changing the toolbar size but they all seem static and not something that can be changed with the tap of a button. Any suggestions on how to do this? Perhaps a different solution altogether?

Comment: Might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992864/custom-uitoolbar-resize-with-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a normal UIView and customize it so it looks like a `UIToolbar`, then just set constraints using AutoLayout and animate the height-constraint.